# How to speed up aggregation query including date string comparisons in array without using $unwind?

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I have a collection which contains documents with nested arrays. There are 1 million documents with thousands of objects in `subfield` array. Documents are quite large, but for purpose of explaining consider the following two documents:

```
[
  {
    "id": "myid",
    "field": {
      "total": 1,
      "subfield": [
        {
          "somefield": "1000",
          "time": "2020-08-06T08:33:57.977+0530",
          "val": [
            {
              "x": "someval",
              "a": "val1",
              "b": "val2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "somefield": "2000",
          "time": "2020-05-08T04:13:27.977+0530",
          "val": [
            {
              "x": "someval2",
              "a": "val1",
              "b": "val2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "myid2",
    "field": {
      "total": 1,
      "subfield": [
        {
          "somefield": "1001",
          "time": "2020-07-31T10:15:50.184+0530",
          "val": [
            {
              "x": "someval2",
              "a": "val1",
              "b": "val2"
            },
            {
              "x": "someval2",
              "a": "val1",
              "b": "val2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Use case:

I need to project only the `id` of documents with `time` date(grouped by date) greater than a value and `field. subfield.val.b` or `field. subfield.val.a` with a particular value.

I have the query to achieve my use case using `$unwind`,`$toDate`,`$dateToString`  operators.

But the use of `$unwind` for large arrays causes the overall set to use a lot of memory and slows things down. It takes more than 15 minutes now.(I have not added any indexes because even if I create indexes for `created`, when I run explain for aggregation, the winning query does not use the provided index)

My current query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$field.subfield",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$field.subfield.val",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      created_at: {
        $toDate: "$field.subfield.time"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          $expr: {
            $gt: [
              {
                "$dateToString": {
                  "date": "$created_at",
                  "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
                }
              },
              "2020-04-28"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              "field.subfield.val.a": {
                "$eq": "val1"
              }
            },
            {
              "field.subfield.val.b": {
                "$eq": "val1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Query in MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WU1sxpZLCFv)

I need to limit the execution time of the query to less than 30 seconds. I hope the process can be made faster if done without `$unwind`.

> My MongoDB Server version is 4.0.3

What are the other possible optimisations that can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is to do something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pi7EBw31vlC), you can query direct in array elements, there is no need to unwind array, so for `to` and `from` you can directly match/query first. second suggestion is why can't you convert this date `"2020-04-28"` to iso date in client side and then match.

Comment: @ turivishal Thank you for your suggestion! I also have another queries to run in the same collection that compares date string in %Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S format. That is why I decided to convert it in the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible optimisations that can be done:

1. Since `$unwind` slows down the query, `$filter` can be used to get matching results from nested array.
2. Date string comparisons are heavy, So its better to store the dates as MongoDB date object and do all the comparisons with date type itself instead of date string type.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "obj1": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$field.subfield",
          "as": "el",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$gt": [
                  "$$el.time",
                  new Date("2020-04-29")
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      id: 1,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "obj1.val.a": {
            "$eq": "val1"
          }
        },
        {
          "obj1.val.b": {
            "$eq": "val1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KraENM-xjog)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the $elemMatch? It works really similar to the js function Array.some()

More info under https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

```js
{
    $match:{
      histories:{
        $elemMatch:{
          created_at:{
            $gt:'2020-04-28'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```